# General template (node.tpl.php) being used instead of specific template (node-article.tpl.php)

Tags: theming

I'm creating my sub-theme based on Zen's starterkit. I copied node.tpl.php from zen to my theme and started making some customizations. Then I realized that I really only wanted those customizations to happen to the Article content type, so I renamed my subtheme's node.tpl.php to node-article.tpl.php but when I do it doesn't get used when I'm viewing my front page which has a list of articles. If I rename it back to node.tpl.php then it immediately gets used again. Back to node-article.tpl.php and I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Drupal 7? If so, you should just leave `node.tpl.php` as it was originally and call your customized version `node--article.tpl.php`.

If you are using D6 you are naming the file right, you should just leave a copy of the original `node.tpl.php` in your subtheme folder.

Comment: Ah, that was it! Yes, I'm using Drupal 7, I didn't realize I needed two dashes. The file works when named node--article.tpl.php